# Trouble with my website and IE7

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer

Sorry I'm new here but I have a serious problem:
I changed the CSS style sheet for IE7 for my [site](http://bumblebbids.com), but now when using IE7 it has no graphics and all of the scripts code is printed.

I have tried replacing the original stylesheet but it made no difference, so please suggest ways that I can fix this? If not, would it be possible to have an "Incompatible browser" message that only appears for IE7 users?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the correct style sheet is arriving in IE7? Can you try a guest or new user?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply with the same account - that one is not working; I'm really sorry if these questions sound ridiculous, but I'm only a student; Is there a way of checking if a stylesheet has successfully linked? I tried deleting the stylesheet and it made no difference so this could be the problem?

Comment: I visited your site, and the site loaded and displayed just fine in IE 7. It could be that there are problems specific to your web browser. Make sure you clear your browser cache, and if the problem persists, try accessing the site from another computer outside your office.

Answer (score 1):

Check the images and how you link them. They should be like this URL: `/Images/image.jpg`. The / at the beginning of the path is all important. This tells the browser and the server to "start looking for this image from the main folder".

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Mick's reply, to help diagnose this particular problem you should use absolute URLs in your stylesheet and it would help for you to use some developer tools. Since IE7 is a bit dated, it doesn't come standard with debugging tools, but there is hope for us. You should give [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) a run and if needed, use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to supplement it. I've discovered that with these utilities, IE7 isn't that stressful to debug now.